# Magento 1.9 https ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: magento-1.9, redirect, ssl, https

Could you please help us with the following?

We have some problems while trying to activate SSL on this site.

- Certificates are correctly installed (verified with subdir).
  [image]
- If we set url configs as default, the page loads only html because magento tries to load css and js as mixed content(http).

Console errors:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https//clubmedico.mx/' was loaded over
>   HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet
>   'http://clubmedico.mx/skin/frontend/tm_themes/theme341k/css/module/aw_blog.css'.
>   This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

.

- If we set web/**un**secure/base_js_url, media and css pointing to  {{secure_base_url}}js/(media and css respectively) instead {{unsecure_base_url}} the page loads almost completely, except many <a>links wich are still pointing to http:.

Also "admin page" and "checkout page" throws ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error.

This is the configuration with less errors we can get so far:

[image]

We really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: We are behind a load balancer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the load balancer
[image]